# Highcharts, display a text who follow selected point during a zoom

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I can display a text near a point, but in fact, this text is not attached to the point. And the text don't follow the point during a zoom.

I make this code and **it's work** :

```
events: {
    redraw: function() {
        $.each(chart.getSelectedPoints(), function(i, point) {
            $('#txt-'+point.x+'-'+point.y)
            .attr('y', point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10)
                .find('tspan')
                .attr('x', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10);
        });
    }
},
```

And this function is called on point select event :

```
function addText(point) {
    chart.renderer.text(
        'paf!',
        point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10,
        point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
    ).attr({
        zIndex: 5,
        id: 'txt-'+point.x+'-'+point.y
    }).add();
}
```

Complete code : http://jsfiddle.net/ManUtopiK/XaURC/

I just want to know if there is another and *official* way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't follow, because when you use Renderer to add point, then you define position in pixels, i.e x: 100px, y:100px and after zoom pixels in a chart are in the same place as without zoom. In other works, when you use Renderer, you don't define position like x:3 and y:4 which is related to chart, but in the pixels.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. Look at the code, x and y change on the fly with .attr('y'... This work ! Just I would like to know if there is an more elegant way to do that

Comment: At this moment it is only this way, which you use.